# Replace existing pages with new pages, keep menu links

Tags: plugins, posts, pages, mysql, customization

I basically want a plugin or method that would give the same functionality as 'Enable Media Replace' but for replacing pages and posts, instead of redirecting, or manually editing.
I've searched high and low and while I've found similar, or workarounds, or manual editing of DB, these weren't ideal, or beyond my abilities.

I'm redesigning an existing WP site, have changed template and have added many new pages, with multiple template level customisations (on >20 pgs), but want to keep the existing (google indexed) links throughout intact - and not have to change menu.

I'd like to ideally: Change urls, slugs, etc of my NEW pages to match these existing links sitewide (leaving existing redundant &/or deleted).

Is there a plugin or method that would be faster than me deleting and manually renaming all the new pages?

Comment: Sorry, but why not edit the existing pages?

Comment: Because the new pages are entirely new content, with multiple changes at the Wordpress and New Template level - it's not just content in the textbox. They are also synced with original Gdocs and have defined a workflow for a copywriter and revisions that will occur.

Comment: I realised the description was misleading, have updated it.

Comment: Why have I been downvoted for this? I may have been unclear to start with, yet I quickly clarified. 
If it has an obvious answer please provide it - I haven't been able to find it. Note that i'm talking about REPLACING pages/DB ref's, keeping links and the existing menu, and not redirecting any pages.
I also understand there are ways I can do this manually, I was looking for a more streamlined method. Thanks

Comment: Also looking for this feature.. I understand exactly what you need. E.g. I created a new design for /page-1 as /page-1-new so I could test a few things get design right, etc. I want to simply be able to replace /page-1 with /page-1-new ... overwrite prior tags etc.. I imagine the plugin would simply say "update as" and give you the option to select a pre-existing url and and then confirm to overwrite a different page. At that point, I can simply delete the /page-1-new, and move along with life.

Comment: Yeah you got it @JakeBohall , seems bizarre it doesn't exist, or I haven't found it yet. I gave up, how about you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was shocked to see that such a simple thing is not readily supported.

I was even more shocked to see that no one had a good answer here on StackExchange!

Happily, I found this post:

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/updating-current-page-with-new-built-page/

...and am grateful for the answer provided by Joy (@joyously on WordPress.org and Slack)

"If you need to build a new version over a long period of time, start a new page and only save Draft. [You can also save and publish as another page name so others can review it while under construction.] When it is ready, go into the Text mode of the editor and copy all. Then go to the old page Text mode and select all, and paste. Then save the old page (with new content)."

So:

1. Use the text-mode editor to copy the content of the new page.
2. Open the old page, go to text-mode editor and paste the copied content from the new page.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I found your post when I was looking to do the same thing. I don't know if I am too late for you, but maybe someone else will benefit.

I have used a simple, free, effective plugin called 'Page Links To'

It puts an extra box near the bottom of each editing page, and defaults to 'its normal Wordpress url'. But you can change it to redirect to a custom url, for which I am using the replacement page on the same site. Redirect is quick and effective.

I don't know enough about Google to know how it affects rankings etc, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mike, yet this is a 301 redirect and there are many plugins that provide same functionality.
The problem with this, while it's a SEO safe way of redirecting, it keeps all the redundant pages in the DB and menu, I was hoping to avoid this by replacing the existing pages. Thanks again

Comment: It also adds loadtime to the viewer, and server, no big deal, but not ideal ;)